# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED on GAE/Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-bigquery

I am developing GAE/Go application and trying to connect Google Big Query from local development server.

My code is like this.

```
import (
  "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
  "golang.org/x/net/context"
  "google.golang.org/api/option"
  gaeLog "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
  newappengine "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func MyFunc(c *gin.Context) {
  r := c.Request
  ctx := newappengine.NewContext(r)
  client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, PROJECT_ID, option.WithServiceAccountFile(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH))
  if err != nil {
      (Error Handling)
  }

  tableList := client.Dataset(DATASET_ID).Tables(ctx)
  for {
    v, err := tableList.Next()
    if err == iterator.Done {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        gaeLog.Errorf(ctx, "Failed to get meta-info: %v", err)
        return
    }
    :
  }
}
```

I invoked local development server with `goapp.bat serve` command.
When I posted a request, I got an error.

```
api_dev.go:344: ERROR: Failed to get meta-info: Get https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/datasets/mydataset/tables?alt=json&pageToken=: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: API error 6 (urlfetch: SSL_CERTIFICATE_ERROR): [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

I googled "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED", but all I can find is python program. My application is GAE/Go program.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: try to see if this solution works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221963/google-app-engine-ssl-certificate-error/43233424#43233424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Google has updated their server certificates but have not notified the Go SDK team of this, which still has the old certs.

The solution seems fairly simple.

1. Go to `google_appengine\lib\cacerts\`
2. Rename `cacerts.txt` to `cacerts.txt.old`, and `urlfetch_cacerts.txt` to `urlfetch_cacerts.txt.old`
3. Download the [Python Linux SDK 1.9.52](https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.52.zip).
4. In this Python SDK there's also `google_appengine\lib\cacerts\` directory with those two cert files. Copy them over to your Go SDK.
5. Rejoice! You now have newer certs.

Comment: I upgraded from 1.9.50 to 1.9.53, I had to get the cacerts.txt and urlfetch_cacerts.txt from 1.9.50 to get it to work again. Tried 1.9.52 and 1.9.51 with no success.