# Google App Engine SSL Certificate Error

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, ssl-certificate

I'm using IntelliJ IDE, I have installed google cloud sdk, google app engine sdk, python. but when I'm trying to go through ItelliJ>>tools>>google app engine for php >> upload app engine php app. but I"m getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5521, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5512, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2975, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5168, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3900, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3921, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    updatecheck.CheckForUpdates()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\sdk_update_checker.py", line 245, in CheckForUpdates
    runtime=runtime))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 246, in Send
    url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1584, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1332, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1268, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1037, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

There is certificate file available on this path: google_appengine\lib\cacerts\cacerts.txt

also I have authenticated using gcloud shell and setup proper project. and in ItelliJ app.yml set same project id.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a similar error (on linux) when trying to run the development server after upgrading the GAE SDK from `1.9.49` (which worked fine) to currently latest `1.9.51`.

After digging on SO and finding suggestions for renaming/removing the `cacerts.txt` file equivalent to the one you mentioned I tried it, but it didn't help - some other related error popped up.

So I just copied over the respective `cacerts.txt` file from the 1.9.49 SDK and things are working fine again.

Comment: thanks for help. 
I have changed cacerts.txt  and its worked for me.

Comment: I upgraded from 1.9.50 to 1.9.53, I had to get the cacerts.txt and urlfetch_cacerts.txt from 1.9.50 to get it to work again. Tried 1.9.52 and 1.9.51 with no success.

Comment: I encountered the same error on Linux with 1.9.50. But it was resolved by updating to 1.9.77.