# gcloud crashed (SSLHandshakeError) in gcloud app deploy

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, gcloud

Unable to deploy my app as I started getting below error since today morning. 
I have tried `gcloud info --run-diagnostics` and `gcloud components reinstall` without much help.

I tried to deploy it using the old `Google App Engine Launcher` for Windows but faced the same error. 
Earlier it worked till yesterday night (IST) using gcloud. Please help!

I am on latest gcloud sdk and have updated all its components. I use Win10. I tried rebooting my laptop as well.

```
C:\gaurav\coding\python\myapp\myapp\dist>gcloud app deploy --project=myproject --version 1 --verbosity=info ./app.yaml
INFO: Refreshing access_token
ERROR: gcloud crashed (SSLHandshakeError): [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics

C:\gaurav\coding\python\myapp\myapp\dist>
```

Diagnostics Output.

```
C:\gaurav\coding\python\myapp\myapp\dist> gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
    Cannot reach https://accounts.google.com (SSLHandshakeError)
    Cannot reach https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects (SSLHandshakeError)
    Cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform (SSLHandshakeError)
Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.


Do you have a network proxy you would like to set in gcloud (Y/n)?  n

ERROR: Network diagnostic (0/1 checks) failed.


C:\gaurav\coding\python\myapp\myapp\dist>
```

Although `gcloud info --run-diagnostics` complains that the three URLs are not reachable. I am able to open them from web browser.

Answer (score 7):

I found that when using Fiddler (for viewing network traffic) and have decrypting https traffic enabled, then I received the SSLHandshakeError.

Stopping the tool (or choosing not to decrypt https traffic) and then running the gcloud resulted in success.

---

According to the comments, also a problem with other web debugging proxies such as Charles.

Comment: Do you suggest that a proxy or something may be decrypting and re encrypting my packets using an additional certificate installed on my laptop ?

Comment: Possibly. Did you attempt @Dan Cornilescu's fix?

Comment: No. My laptop got replaced around the same time. And then I started using the Cloud Shell for deployment.

Comment: I had the same with Charles!  Late night and I didn't catch it :)  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

A problem in recent GAE and GCloud SDK versions is the presence of invalid SSH certificates, see, for example, [Google App Engine SSL Certificate Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221963/google-app-engine-ssl-certificate-error) and [issue 38338974](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38338974).

You could try to use my suggested solution in the above-mentioned post and replace your SDK's certificate file with a valid one (will have to locate a good one for the gcloud SDK, my answer was for the GAE SDK).

You *might* also be able to use the [`gcloud config`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/) command to set the `core` `custom_ca_certs_file` configurable property to point to a file with up to date certificates, if you have one. I didn't try it, YMMV.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux), after adding the SSL interception certificate to the main certificate store: gcloud config set custom_ca_certs_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to Python 2.7.9 on MacOS High Sierra solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue upon install of the google cloud SDK on MacOS Mojave. I am not behind a corporate proxy, and all the answers on the web seemed to indicate that this was the issue. I noticed in the install.sh script that it takes an environment variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON for the python executable. So, I fixed this by exporting the path to my python 3 executable.

In my case:
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6

The install worked as expected after this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, downloaded the `root/intermediate cert` from one of the google url you get when you run the command: `gcloud info --run-diagnostics` and append to the `cacerts.txt` file that is being used. In my case it was the following one: `google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2/cacerts.txt`

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS Catalina, the solution was to completely [uninstall](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk) gcloud and [reinstall](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive) it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to deploy gcloud and I was getting this error. Here is how I fixed it:

1. Access to Google cloud using Firefox
2. Download certificate. pem file and chain file
3. Append them on `cert.pem` located at:
   `C:\Program Files\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\certifi\cert.pem`
   (using this you are creating custom CA cert file based on your proxy)
4. Update cert file as mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set
   (Absolute path to a custom CA cert file.)

Make sure you have `cert.pem` at the end of path.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a conflict in the python versions. `gcloud` was calling a different version. The solution was to set `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` to point to the correct python (python2 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by installing `gcloud` from `apt-get`. The guide is at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get)