# gcloud crashing due to (SSLHandshakeError): [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL]

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I have installed gcloud sdk by following the link https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. I have also done the proxy configuration using the following link https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings.

```
Google Cloud SDK 288.0.0
alpha 2020.04.03
beta 2020.04.03
bq 2.0.56
core 2020.04.03
gsutil 4.49
kubectl 2020.04.03
```

`gcloud init` is successful and `gcloud info --run-diagnostics` displays no problems. However gcloud crashes for any other commands I run. I have tried the following commands.

```
1. gcloud compute images list
2. gcloud services list
3. gcloud logging logs list
```

Here is the message I get after the crash.

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (SSLHandshakeError): [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Can someone please help.

PS. Here is debug output.

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.compute.images.list] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
INFO: Refreshing access_token
INFO: Display format: "    table(
      name,
      selfLink.map().scope(projects).segment(0):label=PROJECT,
      family,
      deprecated.state:label=DEPRECATED,
      status
    )"
DEBUG: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    display_info=self.ai.display_info).Display()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/display.py", line 483, in Display
    self._printer.Print(self._resources)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/resource_printer_base.py", line 275, in Print
    for resource in resources:
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/compute/images/list.py", line 113, in _FilterDeprecated
    for image in images:
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/lister.py", line 1065, in __call__
    errors=errors):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/request_helper.py", line 204, in ListJson
    for item in _ListCore(requests, http, batch_url, errors, _HandleJsonList):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/request_helper.py", line 134, in _ListCore
    requests=requests, http=http, batch_url=batch_url)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/compute/batch_helper.py", line 106, in MakeRequests
    batch_request_callback=batch_checker.BatchCheck)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/batch.py", line 226, in Execute
    batch_http_request.Execute(http)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/batch.py", line 492, in Execute
    self._Execute(http)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/batch.py", line 449, in _Execute
    response = http_wrapper.MakeRequest(http, request)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 356, in MakeRequest
    max_retry_wait, total_wait_sec))
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 304, in HandleExceptionsAndRebuildHttpConnections
    raise retry_args.exc
SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
ERROR: gcloud crashed (SSLHandshakeError): [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

Comment: Can you run the command with the [`--verbosity=debug`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity) flag in order to see what is causing the error? Also, which version of the Cloud SDK did you install?

Comment: I have added debug output and sdk version to my original question.

Comment: There seem to be many possibilities to the reason for this error, but I think it would be worth for you to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221601/gcloud-crashed-sslhandshakeerror-in-gcloud-app-deploy) other Stack question which mentions ways to solve this. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after some debugging. Seems like firewall was the issue in my case. I shifted to python 3.5 . After which I ran the same command `gcloud compute images list` 
I got the error "Caught socket error, retrying request to url https://compute.googleapis.com/batch/compute/v1". Adding this url to firewall exception solved my issue.